# Why isn't :nth-child working in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff974102.aspx), :nth-child should work in IE9, and I have tried it before and it worked fine, but on [this page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/404), it does not appear to be working. View the page in Chrome to see the intended behavior, and in IE, you'll see that it does not work. You can probably see this with a web inspector, but for your reference, the relevant lines of CSS are;

```
.ad_widget:nth-child(3n+2) { background: #efefef; }
.ad_mrow {background: #efefef;}`
```

I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: [Chrome](http://hypftier.de/dump/so5914888-chrome.png) and [IE9](http://hypftier.de/dump/so5914888-ie9.png) on my machine. Where should I see a difference?

Comment: It's working for me on IE9.0.8112.16421

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For some reason I cannot fathom, IE9 defaults to compatibility mode for looking at intranet sites, or an HTML page stored as a file on a PC. Compatibility mode means 'render stuff like a dumb old browser'. This means that when you're designing stuff for a website and you try to preview from your favourite IDE in IE9, none of the CSS3 stuff works. You have to click on Tools ->' compatibility view settings' in the IE9 menu and then unclick the pesky checkbox that says 'display interanet sites in compatibility view'. From then on the wretched browser works like any sane browser such as Safari. Why did they do it? Heaven only knows, but it has taken me ages to discover this simple fix due to the fact that I kept blaming my code.

Comment: I got it all wrong.. I thought 'render stuff like a dumb old browser' was IE's DEFAULT mode

Comment: It's a late response, but add a meta tag to your HTML head: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: I always set up a local webserver for development tasks (xampp is good). Sort of a best practice and it prevents al kinds of issues like the one you described.

Answer (score 8):

They look the same here. You sure you're not in compatibility mode?

Comment: Side note: You can tell if it's in compat mode by the 2px gray border around the page content. Or by looking into the developer tools.

Comment: It looks like I am in compatibility mode, but I don't know why. I set <!DOCTYPE html>, which should trigger standard mode, and I have no "broken-page" icon to switch between modes.

Comment: Ok, so the issue was that I was testing locally, which for some odd reason forces IE9 into compatibility mode. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to click on Tools ->' compatibility view settings' in the IE9 menu and then unclick the pesky checkbox that says 'display interanet sites in compatibility view'. Then everything works happily from then on. (See my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

My version of IE9 was locked into IE8 rendering mode, which wasn't applying the following selector:

```
 .parentClass > div:nth-child(n+2) .childClass
```

Here is where you can find the options to change it:

[image: Where in IE9 to Adjust Browser and Document mode]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working for me.[image: IE9]

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score -3):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` won't stop quirk mode, `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` does.