# A question on nth CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have 12 divs.

I need to select the ones marked THIS. I was thinking some sort of nth child magic?

Thanks!

ie.

```
<div class="feature"></div>
<div class="feature"></div> -> THIS
<div class="feature"></div>
<div class="feature"></div>
<div class="feature"></div> -> THIS
<div class="feature"></div>
<div class="feature"></div>
<div class="feature"></div> -> THIS
<div class="feature"></div>
<div class="feature"></div>
<div class="feature"></div> -> THIS
<div class="feature"></div>
```

Comment: So what you want is something that selects the 2nd out of each group of three?

Comment: Would you accept an answer that says use unobtrusive JavaScript in an onload to find those 2nd-of-three divs and add a class to them?

Comment: Before I write such a thing, are you allowed to target only CSS3?  If so, go with the nth-child answers.  I'm not aware of any CSS2 selector that can do this. Scratch that - jQuery makes it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [nth-child pseudo-selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) with a number expression:

```
div.feature:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

`3n+2` means every third row starting with the second row.

By the way, the link at SitePoint says that all modern browsers except IE8 support have full support.  IE9 has full support, but [make sure you are not in compatibility mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914888/why-isnt-nth-child-working-in-ie9/5914930#5914930).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at needing the selector `:nth-child(3n+2)`.

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Answer (score 0):

Building off ob Sarfraz's answer, `N` can be set to `3n - 1`

```
.feature:nth-child(3n-1){ ... }
```