# alternate coloring of div elements css

Tags: css

i have the following DOM elements:

```
<div class="document>
  <div class="text"> some text1 </div>
  <div class="text"> some text2 </div>
  <div class="text"> some text3 </div>
  <div class="text"> some text4 </div>
</div>
```

i want to color them alternately, meaning text1, text3 are same color and text2, text4 are of same color. 
how can this be done using css?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With css alone you can use

```
.text:nth-child(odd)
{
    color: green;
}
```

But it's CSS3 only

Comment: Do note that the `nth-child` selector was first added in Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: @LachlanMcDonald That's why I noted that it's CSS3 which is only supported by IE9+

Comment: @user902620: This solution should have worked. I've edited this answer to make it more obvious that it's working. Are you testing it in a modern browser?

Comment: IE9 will run local files in compatibility mode, which seems to be a common complication. See this Stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914888/why-isnt-nth-child-working-in-ie9

Answer (score 2):

see the demo on **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/QQykQ/)**

```
.text:nth-child(odd)
{
    color: green;
}
.text:nth-child(even)
{ 
      color:Red;
}
```

This was introduced in 2001. Doest work mostly in old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add 2 classes in HTML code?

```
<div class="document>
  <div class="text odd"> some text1 </div>
  <div class="text even"> some text2 </div>
  <div class="text odd"> some text3 </div>
  <div class="text even"> some text4 </div>
</div>
```

And then, apply color by those class...

Comment: sorry i asked an aswer for the existing dom.

Comment: The nth-child tag is not ready for prime time yet, save yourself a headache!