# KnockoutJS - why $root function doesn't execute within foreach?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to set alternate color background for table rows with knockoutJS.

As you can see, after the data is generated, everything is fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/j8c8aywe/3/

but, try to remove any contact, let's say `the third row`. Then the `last row` shouldn't be red, but it is. Looks like the root `check` function is not executed. Why ??

### edit:

Finally ! It works: http://jsfiddle.net/j8b45mgj/5/

I don't look at the `self.contacts().length` anymore and I don't set `index = 0` after add a new person

Comment: For this scenario you should use `$index` instead of messing with a function: `<tr data-bind='css:{a : ($index() + 1) % 2 == 0}'>` http://jsfiddle.net/z4gbknp0/ By the way your function is not executed because knockout is only looking for observable changes. Your check function does not contain/access any observables so knockout does not reaevaluate the css binding when you remove an item from the list.

Comment: you're right, http://jsfiddle.net/j8c8aywe/6/ but try to add and then remove the added row - you will see that the color jumps between rows...

Comment: You can do this [purely with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090011/alternate-coloring-of-div-elements-css), assuming that alternating colours is what you're after here, and this isn't being used as an example of the function call not working how you expect.

Comment: Here it is applied to [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n45dgena/1/)

Comment: I know that I can do it only with pure CSS, but why if I do it with some variable increment jsfiddle.net/j8c8aywe/6 then It doesn't work as expected ? Because let's say I don't do it in table, but in nested divs, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Fair enough - I figured there might be more to it :)

Comment: [Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/eam2mbuk/1/) - I moved the function call to a span so we can see more easily what's happening.  Seems like knockout is rendering the new element _first_.

Comment: hmm when I add a new person, I set index = 0,that's why you see 1 in the new row

Comment: Yes - but it's rendering that one first and then doing all the others _again_.  I didn't think knockout would even re-render the other rows, but it seems like it is.  Setting it back to 0 wouldn't be a problem if it re-rendered them all in order either.  Just odd that if it's re-rendering them all, why it does the new one first, then all the others above it

Comment: add a new person and see what's the console output http://jsfiddle.net/j8b45mgj/4/ - after add knockout goes with foread and after then moves on with therest ofthe code.

Comment: That's just weird...