# CSS hover effects and other styling is not working on a remote desktop intranet

Tags: css, asp.net, stylesheet, remote-desktop, intranet

I am facing a challenge where only some of a series of CSS hover effects work well in my development environment, but utterly fail in a remote desktop intranet platform. The odd thing is other hyperlink hover effects work fine, but the particular hover effects that are not working are these:

```
.list tr:hover:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#F5FD72; cursor: pointer; }
.list tr:hover:nth-child(even) { background-color:#F5FD72; cursor: pointer; }
.list tr:nth-child(odd), .justList tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#FFFFFF; }
.list tr:nth-child(even), .justList tr:nth-child(even)   { background-color:#E3EAEB; }
```

As the user moves his/her mouse over the table rows a pointer should appear and the whole row should change color. Most all the other hyperlinks for website navigation work fine. I appreciate any insight as to cause of this phenomenon and the steps to fix it.

Comment: without some html code is very hard to tell what's wrong. Please include fiddle or something

Comment: Is your remote computer using a browser that doesn't support 'nth-child'?

Comment: Thanks Fabio and '3rror404'! -- I will try to add some html soon. In the mean time I now see the importance of knowing the client's 'official' browser is Internet Explorer 11. I tested using Chrome and the effects were working. -- Still testing and troubleshooting.

Comment: To anyone following this post I found this somewhat related post on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914888/why-isnt-nth-child-working-in-ie9, which helped me find a solution. === THE SOLUTION: in Internet Explorer 11 go to [Tools]=>[Compatibility View Settings] in the popup dialog remove the site if it is in there, and uncheck the box for 'Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View'. The CSS hover effects started working immediately! (:-D)