# Why is IE9 ignoring my !important CSS for float?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

The text is in the following div:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 column">
```

The CSS for that particular combination says:

```
.lte9 [class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

That is making some of the text in that div to float to the right, which we don't want. But we need to keep that CSS style around for some other HTML that references it that DOES need to float right, such as images. **Bottom line: I can't mess with that style.**

So, I changed the div to be the following:

```
<div class="fsre small-12 medium-6 large-4 column">
```

Note the addition of "fsre" as an additional class.

The corresponding CSS is:

```
.lte9 .fsre [class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child {
    float: left !important;
}
```

So now both styles are in the CSS, but one contains .fsre and one doesn't. Yet when the page is rendered, the .fsre CSS isn't loaded.

Can anyone broaden my CSS horizons as to why I'm failing to get this working on IE9?

Comment: Is it running in compatibility mode by chance?

Comment: I don't know. I will go check that right now. Could you explain (or point me to an online resource) why that could be an issue?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914888/why-isnt-nth-child-working-in-ie9

Comment: Okay that's actually really interesting. My conundrum now is potentially what do I tell the shareholder? Is the only fix for this seemingly that the end user has to change their browser settings?

Comment: You can prevent compatibility mode by adding the following in your `<head>` tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Comment: Alright I'll give that a shot. From what I'm seeing, compatibility mode isn't "pressed" in the nav bar, but it seems like from that other thread, IE9 just does it anyway.

Comment: And, thank you by the way. You've been very helpful in teaching me something new :)